# It is one of the worst things that have/has faced our world?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> “It is one of the worst things that have/has faced our world.“

Would “have” or “had” be correct?

Comment: Things have faced our world, but it has faced our world.  So, tell us first which word or idea you want the pronoun "that" to reference.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "that the world has faced"? The world faces a threat, the threat doesn't face the world.

Comment: One of the worst things **we have faced** in our world. People face things, things do not.

Answer (score 1):

The verb has to agree with the subject of the sentence, which is "it." So the correct answer is actually:

> It is one of the worst things that **has** faced our world.

Answer (score 0):

one of the worst things represents One among multiple things which has to be singular so when talk about singular thing verb must agree with the subject 
i.e.
Subject(singular)+Helping Verb (Singular)+ Object so correct answer will be

“***It is one of the worst things(Singular)*** that ***has(Singular)*** faced our world.“